# Incoherence using Euler's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Using the relation $\ e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ and substituting for $\ x = \pi$, we have the well-known Euler identity, $ e^{i\pi} = -1$. Substitute also for $ x = -\pi $, we have $ e^{-i\pi} = -1$. So we can say $ e^{i\pi} = e^{-i\pi}$ and taking $\ln$ on both sides, $i\pi=-i\pi$. There is clearly something wrong here. Can some help me to figure out what's wrong?

EDIT : 
I actually had a confusing output from my calculator while trying to solve the problem :
[image]

Comment: The logarithm _is not_ a function for complex numbers (as you discovered ;-) If you look at the values for $e^{i x}$, you see that it is periodic with period $2 \pi$, so the inverse isn't well defined.

Comment: What do you mean saying _The logarithm is not a function for complex numbers_? My calculator gives me $ln(e^{x*i}) = x*i$

Comment: Then your calculator is doing it wrong. What calculator is this?

Comment: It's TI NSpire CX Cas, the best one as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{ix}=e^{iy}\implies e^{i(x-y)}=1=e^{2n\pi i}$ as $e^{2n\pi i}=\cos2n\pi+i\sin2n\pi=1$

$\implies x-y=2n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Got your logic but still, can't see why mine is wrong...

Comment: Your calculation can be true if and only if $ln$ be a one-to-one function and $ln$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm is multi-valued.  So we define a branch cut of the logarithm as a principal branch along an axis (or any line) so that we only use one cycle of phase of period $2 \pi$; this keeps that principal branch as a single-valued function.

Answer (score 0):

In definition of $ln(z)$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ we have:
$$ln(x+iy)=ln(|x|)+iArg(y)$$
Since $Arg$ can achive multi values by difference $2k\pi$ so $ln(x+iy)=ln(x+i(y+2k\pi))$.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest software, I am using OS 3.6. Also set calculator  Document Settings Page (Home -> 5: Settings -> 2: Document Settings) on the Real or Complex line - Select Rectangular instead of real. Good Luck Benny
[image]